# Valid newcommand construct dumps me out of mathmode

Tags: macros, equations, environments

I have defined `\newcommand \xbar[1] {$\overset{-}{#1}$}`. `\xbar{arg}` works fine except in `equation` environment. When I use it in `equation` environment (as in: `\xbar{x} = formula`)  it drops me out of math mode and typesets the formula as regular text. If I leave it out the formula displays correctly. I can get around the problem by using `\overset{-}{x} = formula`, but would like to understand why the former doesn't work.

Comment: Got it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

you should not have `$` in the definition. `$` starts and ends math mode so if you have

```
\newcommand\zz{$x$}
```

then if used in text it will give a math x but if used in math

```
$w + \zz + y$
```

is

```
$w + $x$ +y$
```

so stops and starts math mode.